# Communicating using socketio in Android - socket.emit error

Tags: java, android, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to communicate to my nodejs application using android as client. Currently I'm using https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client repository as reference. Tried the examples of repo but no help.

NodeJS-SocketIO Code:

```
socket.on('new user',function(data, callback){
    if (nicknames.indexOf(data)!=-1){
        callback(false);
    } else{
        callback(true);
        socket.nickname = data;
        nicknames.push(socket.nickname);
        updateNicknames();
    }
});
```

Android-Java Code:

```
try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.putOpt("data", "user1");
                socket.emit("new user", json);

            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, the above code results in TypeError: undefined. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do away with the `JSON object`. You could just do:

```
socket.emit("new user", "user1");
```

Not so sure about sending a JSON over, but if you wanted to, did you try:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put("data", "user1");
socket.emit("new user", array);
```

Pretty sure JSONs need to have the enclosing brackets.

Comment: still the same. Error occurs at callback(true) at NodeJS(server-side).

Comment: @JaswanthKumar sorry I don't really know NodeJS. afraid I can't help you on the server side.

Comment: how can I install the library for *socket* ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales did you follow the directions here? [https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)